# How to join corresponding values of two arrays?

Tags: python

Suppose I have two arrays of equal length like this:

```
A = [0 0 1 0 1 3 4 3]

B = [1 2 1 3 4 1 2 3]
```

I want an output which joins the corresponding values like:

```
[0:1 0:2 1:1 0:3 1:4 3:1 4:2 3:3]
```

Comment: What does this mean? ` [0:1 0:2 1:1 0:3 1:4 3:1 4:2 3:3]`. Please explain your output.

Comment: Your output is not valid Python

Comment: Your input is not valid python.

Comment: @DanielMesejo: Neither is the input BTW.

Comment: @Poojan I was reading about the concept of dictionary. So, I am asking is it also possible to join corresponding numbers of two different arrays of equal length.

Comment: @MustafaJaved Dictionary can not have duplicate keys. It can only have unique keys. For your desired output it looks like you want something like `list of tuples` or `list of list`.

Comment: @Poojan ok I got it. So for this case using dictionary is useless?

Comment: Not necessarily, you can have a dictionary with lists as values

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service.   You should invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer for solving your problem.

Comment: @Poojan What I actually want is. If I enter value from first array it should give me the corresponding value of the second array. Because in my case both arrays have equal length.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please show what parts you can do. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3, 4, 3]

B = [1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3]

joined = [{a:b} for a, b in zip(A, B)]  # list of dicts

print(joined)
```

Output:

```
[{0: 1}, {0: 2}, {1: 1}, {0: 3}, {1: 4}, {3: 1}, {4: 2}, {3: 3}]
```

Or instead perhaps:

```
joined = list(zip(A, B))  # list of tuples
print(joined)
```

Output:

```
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (0, 3), (1, 4), (3, 1), (4, 2), (3, 3)]
```

Comment: Thank you.It worked for my data